# Laravel naming multiple model class name who are related with each other

Tags: php, laravel

i'm just thinking here, i had multiple tables related to the student, things like: history, bulletin, parents, course, and a lot more... when i need create a new student, all this tables need to be filled. i'm using Laravel and the recomended is create a model to each table, my problem is now, naming the model name, what's the best aproach? model with table name or a name related to what the model is?

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Comment: Well you can name it anything you want as long as the model name is clear on what it should store.

Comment: As I know a good practice is to name the model at singular while the table plural. Eg. model: Bulletin, table: bulettins, model: Parent, table: parents. I guess the logic is that the Model should be singular because it represents a single db row/entry. But sure you can name them as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are many conventions for "Models" - Laravel just doesn't bottleneck you or your project into using any one method as long as the model name is clear and has its own table you are following best practices.

for organizational purposes you can add all the related models under the same folder,this is something for you (and your development team, if you're a part of one) to decide on.

```
   ├── app
   │   ├── Models <---- folder
   │   │   ├── Students <---- folder
   │   │   │   ├── Student.php    \
   │   │   │   ├── History.php     \ ____ Models
   │   │   │   ├── Bulletin.php    /
   │   │   │   ├── Course.php     /
```